# Can we listen into events from OpenCTI app in Salesforce?

Tags: opencti, cti

We use a very basic OpenCTI app from a vendor, we are trying to extend the functionality to create both Case and Account when the caller is not found in our DB. The Call Centre app already allows this partially but only one object (either Account or Case, but not both).

The app vendors package is managed so we cannot alter the code. What I want to know is what other options do we have? Is it possible to listen into the when a "call" is made and have it run some actions?

Comment: Are you using Lightning or Classic and are you using the Console?

Comment: We’re using Lightning